# Unity. плавный поворот Transform при нажатии кнопки

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я пытаюсь сделать анимацию, которая будет отображать взмах мечом при атаке. Мне необходимо плавно поворачивать `_weaponTrasnform` в течении времени `animationTime` на угол `tangle`. Пока все, что делает этот код, это мгновенно перемещает оружие в конечную позицию. Я новичок в Unity и C# и не понимаю, что я делаю не так.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class PlayerAttackController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform _weaponTrasnform;
    [SerializeField] private PlayerWeapon _weaponData;
    [SerializeField] private UnityEvent attackEvent;

    private bool attackEloved = true;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && attackEloved)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Attack());
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator Attack()
    {
        attackEvent?.Invoke();
        attackEloved = false;
        AttackAnimation();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(_weaponData.AttackTimeOut);
        attackEloved = true;
    }

    public void AttackLogout()
    {
        print("Attack");
    }

    private void AttackAnimation()
    {
        float tangle = 90f;
        float animationTime = 50f;
        float currenTime = 0f;

        Quaternion start = _weaponTrasnform.rotation;
        Quaternion target = Quaternion.Euler(0, tangle, 0);

        while (currenTime < animationTime)
        {
            float t = Mathf.SmoothStep(0f, 1f, currenTime / animationTime);
            _weaponTrasnform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(start, target, t);
            currenTime += Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать проще:

Попробуйте сделать анимацию через окно Animation (Window > Animation > Animation или Ctrl+6 на винде) и повесить её на игрока через Add Component > Animation. И в нужный момент запускать анимацию через код:

```
public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animation anim;
    public GameObject Player;

    void Start()
    {
        anim = Player.GetComponent<Animation>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && attackEloved)
        {
            anim.Play();
        }
    }  
}
```

Больше информации по анимациям можно взять на [оф сайте unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.Play.html).